# Is it possible to simulate other android devices on one of them?

Tags: android, emulation, nexus-7

I want to manually test my android applications on any size and resolution but I have only a Nexus 7. I want to know is it possible to simulate other devices (resolution and screen size) on my Nexus 7? or run android emulator on my device in some way?

Comment: what does "on my N7" mean? Can't you use the Emulator?

Comment: I can use emulator on my PC but it is too slow and annoying. I read somewhere the emulator is programmed for ARM devices and because of that it's slow on x86 processors.I wanted a way to test my apps on any size and resolution with suitable speed and funtionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the density of your device:

https://plus.google.com/+AdamWPowell/posts/cz5TxuoNDfG